# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.createGraph

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, graphframes

I wanted to install graphframes for spark following the instructions on the spark website, but the command:

> `pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12`

did not work for me.

I tried many ways to install, but decided to stay at downloading graphframes `.jar`, adding it to the general list of Spark `.jar` files and adding it manually in the code `spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("path to /spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/graphframes-0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12.jar")`.
After that, the library is imported, but there is always an error when creating the GraphFrame. And I just have no idea how to solve it.

> My `.bashrc` variables:
> export CLASSPATH="/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars"
> export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/conf"
> export HADOOP_HOME="/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7"
> export HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER=ERROR,console
> export JAVA_HOME="/home/german/jdk1.8.0_301"
> export SPARK_CLASSPATH="/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars"
> export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars"
> export SPARK_HOME="/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7"
> export PATH="/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/bin:$PATH"
> export PYTHONPATH="/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib:/home/german/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python:$PYTHONPATH"

> My jdk version 1.8, python 3.7.10, OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    
spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "spark_warehouse")\
                    .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("graphframes_checkpoints")
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("path to /spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/graphframes-0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12.jar")

vertices = spark.read.parquet("tmp_dfs/parquet/vertices.parquet")

edges = spark.read.parquet("tmp_dfs/parquet/edges.parquet")

from graphframes import *
graph = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
```

And I get the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.createGraph.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.graphframes.GraphFrame$.apply(GraphFrame.scala:676)
    at org.graphframes.GraphFramePythonAPI.createGraph(GraphFramePythonAPI.scala:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ee0c1444db6f> in <module>
     37 
     38 from graphframes import *
---> 39 graph = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)

/tmp/spark-9d209109-e503-4ea1-813c-9ca68e76d72a/userFiles-4417833f-c19c-4e6e-9eea-7a21b6553f5f/graphframes-0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12.jar/graphframes/graphframe.py in __init__(self, v, e)
     87                 .format(self.DST, ",".join(e.columns)))
     88 
---> 89         self._jvm_graph = self._jvm_gf_api.createGraph(v._jdf, e._jdf)
     90 
     91     @property

~/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.createGraph.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.graphframes.GraphFrame$.apply(GraphFrame.scala:676)
    at org.graphframes.GraphFramePythonAPI.createGraph(GraphFramePythonAPI.scala:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I may have chosen the wrong installation method or something else. I would be glad to hear any suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with which scala version spark jars are available under $SPARK_HOME/jars folder, example `spark-sql_<scala version>-2.4.7.jar`. If the version is 2.11 then you need to use graphframe which is [compiled with scala v2.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/graphframes/graphframes/0.8.1-spark2.4-s_2.11).

And one more thing, spark version which you are using is 2.4.7 but graphframes jar which you added is related to spark 3.0, this might also cause issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was really in the scala version. After installing `graphframes 0.8.1-spark2.4-s_2.11` everything worked.